# Set scrollLeft/scrollTop simultaneously does not work in Safari 6

Tags: scroll, osx-mountain-lion, scrollto, safari

**When setting the `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` parameters in Safari 6 simultaneously, only one of both gets executed**, scrolling the page only over one axis. This happens both using native JavaScript, jQuery and the [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin.

Example using jQuery's `.animate()`:

```js
$('body').animate({
    'scrollLeft': 100,
    'scrollTop': 100
}, {
    'duration': 500,
    'easing': 'swing'
});
```

I've set up a demo page here: http://nabble.nl/demo/safari6scrollto/

All examples work fine in all major browsers as expected, in Safari 6 only example no. 4, 6 and 7 work.
Somehow, when loading the demo page in an `IFRAME` (see bottom of demo page), everything works just fine.

**Is this a bug in Safari? If so, how to work around this issue? If not, what is causing it and how can this be resolved?**

Other related reports:

- https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/issues/9
- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/scrolltop-scrollleft-not-working-in-safari-6
- http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12588

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get the jquery.scrollTo plugin working on OSX Mountain Lion, and since I couldn't find the specifics on what is causing this behaviour, I put together a rather ugly workaround. It uses `window.scrollTo(x, y)` in the step function of jQuery's `.animate()`, which gives no problems in Safari 6:

```js
var left;
$(window).animate({
    'pageXOffset': 100,
    'pageYOffset': 100
}, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if (fx.prop == 'pageXOffset') {
            left = now;
        } else if (fx.prop == 'pageYOffset') {
            window.scrollTo(left, now);
        }
    }
});
```

*Please note that the step function is called for every animated property, for every element the animation is applied on (in our case just 1: `window`). Hence the intermediate variable to store the current X position in the animation.*

It uses the `pageXOffset` and `pageYOffset` properties of the `window` object, so I don't know how suitable this workaround is for animating the `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` properties of non-window objects.

Anyway, it works for scrolling the entire document, which was all I wanted, and does so very smooth in Safari 6, too!

Comment: Oh and, a quick fix on the jquery.scrollTo plugin:  http://nabble.nl/demo/safari6scrollto/scrollto.js